# Count number of possible paths up ladder

Tags: java, algorithm, fibonacci

I can't seem to come up with an algorithm to solve the following problem, I tried using a series of for-loops but it became way too complicated:

> A ladder has `n` steps, one can climb the ladder using any
>   combination of steps of 1 or steps of 2. How many possible ways are
>   there for one to climb the ladder?

So for example, if the ladder had **3 steps**, these would be the possible paths:

- 1-1-1
- 2-1
- 1-2

And for **4 steps**

- 1-1-1-1
- 2-1-1
- 1-2-1
- 1-1-2
- 2-2

Any insight as to how this could be done would be greatly appreciated. Also, I'm working in Java.

Edit: I was indeed going to be using small `n` values, but it certainly would be neat to know how to manage with larger ones.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding all paths down stairs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5099337/finding-all-paths-down-stairs)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Interestingly, there is a simple solution to this problem. You can use recursion:

```
public static int countPossibilities(int n) {
    if (n == 1 || n == 2) return n;
    return countPossibilities(n - 1) + countPossibilities(n - 2);
}
```

Whenever you're faced with this type of "tricky" problem, bear in mind that the solution is often times quite elegant, and always check to see if something can be done with recursion.

**EDIT**: I was assuming that you would deal with relatively small `n` values in this problem, but if you deal with large ones then the method above will probably take a good amount of time to finish. One solution would be to use a `Map` that would map `n` to `countPossibilities(n)` - this way, there would be no time wasted doing a computation that you've already done. Something like this:

```
private static Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
static {
    map.put(1, 1);
    map.put(2, 2);
}

public static int countPossibilities(int n) {
    if (map.containsKey(n))
        return map.get(n);

    int a, b;

    if (map.containsKey(n - 1))
        a = map.get(n - 1);
    else {
        a = countPossibilities(n - 1);
        map.put(n - 1, a);
    }

    if (map.containsKey(n - 2))
        b = map.get(n - 2);
    else {
        b = countPossibilities(n - 2);
        map.put(n - 2, b);
    }

    return a + b;
}
```

Try this with `n = 1000`. The second method is literally orders of magnitude faster than the first one.

Comment: Wow 1/100th of the number of lines I was using, hehe. Thanks :-)

Comment: @A.R.S When n becomes very large , this algorithm will not scale well , because the subproblems will overlap . Basically you would be solving the same sub problem multiple times in different branches of the recursion tree . A better solution will be to use dynamic programming .

Comment: You can optimize even more if you calculate Fibonacci(n+1) in logarithmic time.

Answer (score 8):

This is in fact closely related to the [Fibonacci sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number), as was mentioned only briefly in one of the comments so far: Each step `n` can be reached from either two steps below (`n-2`) or one step below (`n-1`), thus the number of possibilities to reach that step is the sum of the possibilities to reach those other two steps. Finally, there is exactly one possibility to reach the first step (and the zeroth, i.e. staying on the ground).

Also, as the number of possibilities for step `n` depends only on the results for step `n-1` and `n-2`, it is not necessary to store all those intermediate values in a map or in an array -- the last two are enough!

```
public static long possForStep(int n) {
    // current and last value, initially for n = 0 and n = 1
    long cur = 1, last = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        // for each step, add the last two values and update cur and last
        long tmp = cur;
        cur = cur + last;
        last = tmp;
    }
    return cur;
}
```

This not only reduces the amount of code by a good share, but also gives a complexity of *O(n)* in time and *O(1)* in space, as opposed to *O(n)* in time *and* space when storing all the intermediate values.

However, since even the `long` type will quickly overflow as `n` approaches 100 anyway, space complexity of *O(n)* is not really a problem, so you can just as well go with this solution, which is much easier to read.

```
public static long possForStep(int n) {
    long[] values = new long[n+1];
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        // 1 for n==0 and n==1, else values[i-1] + values[i-2];
        values[i] = (i <= 1) ?  1 : values[i-1] + values[i-2];
    }
    return values[n];
}
```

*Update:* Note that this is close to, but not quite the same as the Fibonacci sequence, which starts `0, 1, 1, 2, 3,...` while this one goes `1, 1, 2, 3, 5, ...`, i.e. `possForStep(n) == fibonacci(n+1)`.

Comment: In fact, the complexity can be reduced to O(logN) using Matrix Exponentiation. You can read more about this here :
http://ronzii.wordpress.com/2011/07/09/using-matrix-exponentiation-to-calculated-nth-fibonacci-number/

Answer (score 1):

I would use dynamic programming and each time solve a problem where the ladder is 1 rung or 2 rungs shorter.

```
def solveLadder(numOfRungs):
  if numOfRungs<=2:
    return numOfRungs
  return solveLadder(numOfRungs-1)+solveLadder(numOfRungs-2)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the fibonacci series. You can solve it elegantly using tail recursive recursion:

```
    let ladder n =
        let rec aux n1 n2 n =
            if n=0 then (n1 + n2)
            else aux n2 (n1+n2) (n-1)
        aux 1 1 (n-2)
```

An easier to understand non-tail recursive code would be:

```
    let rec ladder n =
        if n<=2 then n
        else ladder (n-1) + ladder (n-2)
```

You can easily translate that to Java.

Answer (score -3):

1. List item

This is simple fibonacci series if the no of step we can take is 1 or 2
for

- No of stair       possible case

  1------------------1

  2------------------2

  3------------------3

  4------------------5

  5------------------8

  6------------------13

and so on

Comment: Several other answers have already mentioned that it's Fibonacci series, with proof and algorithms. Repeating the same thing with less info isn't very useful.