# Tribonacci series with different initial values

Tags: algorithm, math

How to find nth tribonacci number with matrix multiplication method if the initial values are some arbitrary numbers say 1, 2 3 i.e T(1) = 1, T(2) =2 and T(3) = 3.

If T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-2) + T(n-3) then how to find T(n) if n is very very large, I would appreciate if anyone can explain with matrix multiplication method. How to construct initial matrix.

Comment: Does it need to necessarily be with matrix multiplication? FYI there are better ways to do it.

Comment: @A.R.S. can u explain your solution with this example please

Comment: @user650521 Refer to this document: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TribonacciNumber.html

Comment: Is there any specific language you're using? The final answer will look something like the answer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12255193/count-number-of-possible-paths-up-ladder/12255200#12255200) question. But you will use not only `a` and `b`, but also a `c` (since its tribonacci not fibonacci). Also, you would just add (3, 3) to the map as well (in that static initializer block).

Comment: @A.R.S. Im using C, but I dont want to use a recurrence relation. It would either consume lot of time or lot of space. If it is fast multiplication method it would solve my problem.

Comment: @iccthedral How to fit my question in that explanation?...Can u help

Comment: @user650521 Just click the edit button under the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The matrix multiplication method involves using the matrix recurrence relation.

For the Fibonacci series, we can define a vector of length 2 to represent adjacent Fibonacci numbers. Using this vector, we can define a recurrence relation with a matrix multiplication:

[image]

Similarly, the Tribonacci series recurrence relation can be written in this way:

[image]

The only difference is that the vector and matrix sizes are different.

Now, to calculate a large Tribonacci number, we just apply the matrix multiplication n times, and we get:

[image]

The matrix to the power of `n` (M<sup>n</sup>) can be efficiently calculated, because we can use an exponentiation algorithm.

Many efficient exponentiation algorithms for scalars are described by Wikipedia in [Exponentiation by Squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring). We can use the same idea for matrix exponentiation.

I will describe a simple way to do this. First we write `n` as a binary number, eg:

```
n = 37 = 100101
```

Then, calculate M to each power of 2 by squaring the previous power of 2: M<sup>1</sup>, M<sup>2</sup> = M<sup>1</sup>M<sup>1</sup>, M<sup>4</sup> = M<sup>2</sup>M<sup>2</sup>, M<sup>8</sup> = M<sup>4</sup>M<sup>4</sup>, M<sup>16</sup> = M<sup>8</sup>M<sup>8</sup>, M<sup>32</sup> = M<sup>16</sup>M<sup>16</sup>, ...

And finally, multiply the powers of M corresponding to the binary digits of `n`. In this case, M<sup>n</sup> = M<sup>1</sup>M<sup>4</sup>M<sup>32</sup>.

After calculating that, we can multiply the matrix with the Tribonacci vector for the first 3 values, ie.

[image]

Because the matrices have fixed size, each matrix multiplication takes constant time. We must do `O(log n)` matrix multiplications. Thus, we can calculate the n<sup>th</sup> Tribonacci number in `O(log n)` time.

Compare this to the normal dynamic programming method, where it takes `O(n)` time, by calculating each Tribonacci number up to the n<sup>th</sup> Tribonacci number (ie. `for (i = 3 to n) {T[i] = T[i-1]+T[i-2]+T[i-3];} return T[n];`).

---

I will assume that you know how to code up matrix multiplication in the language of your choice.

Answer (score 4):

Consider:

```
                           | a1 b1 c1 |
[f(n) f(n - 1) f(n - 2)] * | a2 b2 c2 | = [f(n + 1) f(n) f(n - 1)]
                           | a3 b3 c3 |
```

Find the unknowns in the matrix based on that and that will be the matrix you want.

The answer in this case is:

```
1 1 0
1 0 1
1 0 0
```

The method is general however, it works even if you sum `k` previous terms, even if they have constants in front of them etc.