# Reducing the time complexity of recursive Fibonacci like function in c++

Tags: c++, math, optimization, time-complexity

I have been trying to code a solution for a problem in c++.

**This has to be solved using recursion only**
**The modulo 10000000007 is not the issue the code takes longer with/without it**

The problem:
Davis likes to climb each staircase 1, 2, or 3 steps at a time.

Given the respective heights for each of the n staircases, find and print the number of ways he can climb each staircase , modulo 10^10 + 7

Example
for n=5

The staircase has 5 steps. Davis can step on the following sequences of steps:

1 1 1 1 1

1 1 1 2

1 1 2 1

1 2 1 1

2 1 1 1

1 2 2

2 2 1

2 1 2

1 1 3

1 3 1

3 1 1

2 3

3 2

There are 13 possible ways he can take these 5 steps and 13 modulo 10000000007 = 13

**My solution using recursion so far:**

```
int ways(int n) {
    if(n==1) return 1;
    if(n==2) return 2;
    if(n==3) return 4;
    return (ways(n-3)+ways(n-2)+ways(n-1))%10000000007;
}
```

The code works perfectly but its taking way too long on big computation.
If there is a way to optimize it do share .
simpler the solution the better.
Thanks.

Comment: have you considered `1 << (n - 1)` assuming non-zero values of `n`?

Comment: @Mgetz please elaborate i didn't get the logic

Comment: Does that recursion remind you of Fibonacci?

Comment: Think [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization#:~:text=In%20computing%2C%20memoization%20or%20memoisation,the%20same%20inputs%20occur%20again.). Also, limit only comes into play when 3 to the `n`th power exceeds it.

Comment: in some array keep track what `ways(x)` return for given `x`.

Comment: @YashYadav the binary value `0b010` is 2... e.g. one place shifted over... I'd suggest doing some research on how binary numbers work because your first three `if` statements disappear quickly

Comment: Note also that `10000000007` is [not a prime number](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factorize+10000000007+). So it would be nice to check for Pisano period if it is small it can be used as great leverage.

Comment: @Mgetz `ways(4)` is `7` not `8` and `ways(5) == 13` and doing this for `n<4` is pointless.

Comment: Note that 10000000007 is does not fit in 32 bits and so if `sizeof(int)` is 4 (with `CHAR_BITS` set to 8 like on almost all platforms) then there is an overflow issue. This is often the case (even on 64-bit platforms). Thus, this is probably better to use wider types of such a case (eg. `uint64_t`).

Comment: @JérômeRichard thanks but that part was not the issue however that info will help me a lot .

Comment: @MarekR there is a reason it was a comment and not an answer 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can start adding memoization, to avoid most of the recursive calls.

```
long long ways(long long n)
{
    // Memoization requires to store the previously calculated values.
    static std::map<long long, long long> mem{
        {1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 4}
    };

    // I'm using std::map, but I don't want to use operator[], nor find...
    // https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at
    // https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find
    // https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/lower_bound
    auto it = mem.lower_bound(n);

    // If it has already been calculated, return the stored value.
    if ( it != mem.cend() and it->first == n )
        return it->second;

    // Otherwise evaluate the new value (recursively) and store it
    // Note that I can use the iterator as an hint for the insertion.
    // https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace_hint
    return mem.emplace_hint(
        it, n,
        (ways(n-3) + ways(n-2) + ways(n-1)) % 10000000007
    )->second;
}
```

If it's not enough, you'll have to search for some mathematical trick or just avoid the recursion altogether and use a simple loop.

Comment: That works !!!  Thanks! can you please explain the logic of your code in short ?

Comment: @YashYadav Edited, I hope it's more clear now.

Comment: Using a `std::vector` should much more efficient. This is possible since values are always positive and all values between 0 and n will be memoized.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Well, we don't know how this would be called. As I mentioned, a loop from 1 to n would be much easier and faster and wouldn't require any extra memory other than the last three values.

Comment: @Bob__ Yeah could not use loop as for where its needed .

Answer (score 3):

The algorithm compute a custom **Tribonacci sequence** modulus 10000000007. This can be computed very efficiently in **`O(log n)` time and `O(1)` space** based on a **matrix representation** of the sequence like for *Fibonacci*. See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1859328/fibonacci-using-matrix-representation) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12331134/12939557) for more information.

This method is very fast for big inputs (much faster than using memoization) and very memory efficient.

However, there is a catch: the implementation needs to computation the multiplication of two 64-bit integers modulo a 64-bit integer (unless the modulus can fit in a 32-bit integer). 128-bit integers are not supported on most platforms, but `boost::multiprecision` can be used. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18439520/is-there-a-128-bit-integer-in-c) for more information.

Here is an implementation:

```
int64_t int128_mulMod(int64_t a, int64_t b, int64_t mod)
{
    return int64_t((int128_t(a) * int128_t(b)) % int128_t(mod));
}

// Compute the matrix multiplication of a * b and put the result in a
void matMulMod(int64_t a[3][3], int64_t b[3][3], int64_t mod)
{
    int64_t res[3][3] = {};

    for(int i=0 ; i<3 ; ++i)
        for(int j=0 ; j<3 ; ++j)
            for(int k=0 ; k<3 ; ++k)
                res[i][j] += int128_mulMod(a[i][k], b[k][j], mod);

    for(int i=0 ; i<3 ; ++i)
        for(int j=0 ; j<3 ; ++j)
            a[i][j] = res[i][j];
}

// Compute the matrix exponentiation a^n and put the result in a
void matPowMod(int64_t a[3][3], int64_t n, int64_t mod)
{
    if(n == 0 || n == 1)
        return;

    int64_t m[3][3] = {{ 1, 1, 1 },
                       { 1, 0, 0 },
                       { 0, 1, 0 }};

    // Use recursion to square the matrix efficiently
    matPowMod(a, n / 2, mod);

    // Square the matrix
    matMulMod(a, a, mod);

    // Remainder case
    if(n % 2)
        matMulMod(a, m, mod);

    // Apply the modulus on each term to prevent overflows
    for(int i=0 ; i<3 ; ++i)
        for(int j=0 ; j<3 ; ++j)
            a[i][j] %= mod;
}

int64_t ways_fast(int64_t n)
{
    int64_t a[3][3] = {{ 1, 1, 1 },
                       { 1, 0, 0 },
                       { 0, 1, 0 }};

    if(n==1) return 1;
    if(n==2) return 2;
    if(n==3) return 4;

    matPowMod(a, n, 10000000007ll);
    return a[0][0]; // Result of the Tribonacci sequence
}
```

For example, on my machine, `ways_fast(30'000)` is 100 times faster than computing the memoization-based method provided by @Bob__. Moreover, the memoization algorithm crashes when computing `ways(60'000)` while `ways_fast(200'000)` works correctly.

For more information, please read:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_Fibonacci_numbers
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Matrix_form
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation

Comment: Thanks man . I needed kind of different kind of solution for as to where I have to write it. But this is really cool. Just multiply by the matrix Saving both time and space .