# Time Complexity of the function

Tags: python, list, dictionary, recursion, time-complexity

I got two versions of solving the same question. And I am really confused about how to calculate the time complexity (and chat gpt is confusing me even more lol).

The first version:

```
class Solution:
    def tribonacci(self, n: int) -> int:
        if n == 0:
            return 0
        elif (n == 1) or (n == 2):
            return 1
        else:
            memo = [0,1,1]
            for i in range(3,n+1):
                memo.append(memo[-1] + memo[-2] + memo[-3])
            print(memo)
            return memo[-1]
```

I think the time complexity of this version is O(n) - Just want to confirm if this is correct.

And my second version is:

```
class Solution:
    def tribonacci(self, n: int) -> int:
        memo = {}

        def tribonacci_helper(n):
            if n == 0:
                return 0
            elif n == 1 or n == 2:
                return 1

            if n not in memo:
                memo[n] = tribonacci_helper(n-1) + tribonacci_helper(n-2) + tribonacci_helper(n-3)

            return memo[n]

        return tribonacci_helper(n)
```

I am very confused about what the time complexity is in this (second) case.

And which one in terms of time and space complexity do you think is better?

Chat gpt says the time complexity of the second version is O(n) but I think it is O(3^n) because the `tribonacci_helper` function calls itself 3 times within (but I might be wrong).

Comment: @OM222O You are counting integer operations, but the integers themselves are growing fast. You cannot say that e.g. addition is O(1) if the numbers to be added are unbounded.

Comment: if all the numbers were on that order, maybe you could sell that as a constant. you can't though because `trib(n) ~ exp(n)`, so those numbers grow exponentially, hence their required space (and cost for addition) grows as `n` grows: `bit_length(trib(n)) ~ n`. -- if multiple people say you can't ignore this, perhaps spend some time thinking about what they could mean. your first instinct should not be to defend your opinion but to try to see how the statements of others *could* be true. there's always more for you to learn.

Answer (score 2):

**Both take Θ(n²) time and space.**

That's because they compute ~n sums and those grow exponentially, so their *space* grows linearly. The n-th tribonacci number is about [1.839^n](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_Fibonacci_numbers#%3A%7E%3Atext%3DThe_tribonacci_numbers_are_like%2Cof_the_preceding_three_terms.?wprov=sfla1), so it has about log2(1.839)*n bits, about 0.879n bits. For example, tribonacci(1000) has 878 bits and tribonacci(2000) has 1757 bits, twice as much (as `tribonacci(n).bit_length()` will tell you). You compute each sum only once, and adding takes time linear in the bit-size of the numbers, so overall to compute these ~n sums with an average of 0.879*(n/2) bits takes quadratic time and space. For example for n=1000, the total number of bits `sum(map(int.bit_length, memo))` (in the first version) is 438943 while for n=2000 it is 1757031, about four times as much (as expected from doubling n when you have quadratic complexity).

The second version isn't as bad as you think, because `tribonacci_helper(n-2)` and `tribonacci_helper(n-3)` hit either a base case or an already memoized value, so they take constant time.

I'd say the first version is better as it's simpler and can't run into a recursion depth problems. But better would be to not store *all* numbers but only keep track of the latest three, as that's all you need to continue. That would still take Θ(n²) time but only Θ(n) space. Here's an implementation:

```
class Solution:
    def tribonacci(self, n: int) -> int:
        a, b, c = 0, 1, 1
        for _ in range(n):
            a, b, c = b, c, a+b+c
        return a
```

Benchmark with some solutions for n=20000:

```
 14.49 ± 0.39 ms  Kelly2
 15.11 ± 0.45 ms  Kelly
 25.17 ± 0.89 ms  Kelly3
 36.56 ± 0.60 ms  Original

Python: 3.11.4 (main, Sep  9 2023, 15:09:21) [GCC 13.2.1 20230801]
```

`Kelly2` avoids wastefully computing two larger tribonacci numbers than the one we return, by "going backwards" by 2 steps for the initialization and returning `c`.

`Kelly3` uses a deque that limits itself to 3 elements instead of using 3 variables, which more nicely generalizes to further Fibonacci variations where the next number is the sum of the previous k numbers.

```py
from timeit import timeit
from statistics import mean, stdev
from collections import deque
import sys


class Original:
    def tribonacci(self, n: int) -> int:
        if n == 0:
            return 0
        elif (n == 1) or (n == 2):
            return 1
        else:
            memo = [0,1,1]
            for i in range(3,n+1):
                memo.append(memo[-1] + memo[-2] + memo[-3])
            return memo[-1]


class Kelly:
    def tribonacci(self, n: int) -> int:
        a, b, c = 0, 1, 1
        for _ in range(n):
            a, b, c = b, c, a+b+c
        return a


class Kelly2:
    def tribonacci(self, n: int) -> int:
        a, b, c = 1, 0, 0
        for _ in range(n):
            a, b, c = b, c, a+b+c
        return c


class Kelly3:
    def tribonacci(self, n: int) -> int:
        t = deque([0, 1, 1], maxlen=3)
        for _ in range(n):
            t.append(sum(t))
        return t[0]


funcs = Original, Kelly, Kelly2, Kelly3

for n in range(1000):
    answers = [f().tribonacci(n) for f in funcs]
    assert len(set(answers)) == 1, (n, answers)

n = 20000
times = {f: [] for f in funcs}
def stats(f):
    ts = [t * 1e3 for t in sorted(times[f])[:5]]
    return f'{mean(ts):6.2f} ± {stdev(ts):4.2f} ms '
for _ in range(25):
    for f in funcs:
        t = timeit(lambda: f().tribonacci(n), number=1)
        times[f].append(t)
for f in sorted(funcs, key=stats):
    print(stats(f), f.__name__)

print('\nPython:', sys.version)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=rVRLjtQwEF2x8Slq1zbtbiXpGYQihQuwgH2IWu7EHiwSp4ndA63RnITNbGA_V-AYnIay4_SPWaABb_yrz6tn1_v2Y7t3H3vz8PB959Ti9a8Xj2roO3C6k9qB7rb94OKOhBvrhNPW6dpOt50UhuN5I29Hk7pvW1k73ZuDTSM_7ySJG7u3hJC6FdbCu0HfaCPanACORipwg970RtS1pla2ioPJQRvHYPHGz6OhH1qBgaKA5HjkxyDdbjCQHA5li5Y0mKYM-iGuM_akX3riZ-W5SSe7HgooE57ytDq7UhhXIz4YhLmRdMXNPL1IMEVYiu1Wmob6dblIK5jDuMyOy1XFngI3uRzoeyvbdv8M7gSHDYcai0k4pPykal_I-liIuSji6OgnDmK-mdfkAqY4x5f9E0BEhxiT_wqwPge4egZAhxnCr6ZlpLDi0ImvrTTFiv0tWjd9BrvrqGPsEqgrE__Yamew34pDt_ARd5yyOK_QENOZY7o0SZKYURj7RQ4-SKkoW57UaVhAqbxbSDT-bGRHYrNiPciEo9GfsdBHHJuITzEZIdhRkGGyhHit8FnuVA5ldRH5nniOvYRYqiIwFzA5eAmpXAV75-0tKoVsaAhXqoqV-XU1AovUqNmdVx7qLMtfLTN1Dz8f4S7IUDi7CmedhRm5eITsOqY-B3f-tqPm0VZ0m0bk8Adn-DN23UYORXp8tAns9KiOkUOKWE_IxOGT3BeBhohkO-DnohMxHNRyvTaik-s1kjtezj6Y90Gr8xn3Erq8RepRY9mo3FHAJyH_DQ)

Comment: @KellyBundy how is adding 3 numbers N times O(n^2) instead of O(n)?

Comment: @OM222O What is N? If you mean n, then it's because each addition takes &Theta;(n) average time here. Did you have a look at the total bit lengths I showed?

Answer (score 2):

Please first read [the answer by Kelly Bundy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77542405/time-complexity-of-the-function#77542902). It alerted me to the non-trivial time complexity of this algorithm.

---

At the end I present a version based on matrix exponentiation. Haven't timed it yet but it's in a different time complexity class.

All of this isn't new stuff. A question and answers from a decade ago:

[Tribonacci series with different initial values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12331013/tribonacci-series-with-different-initial-values)

---

First you might want to be aware of the fact that arithmetic isn't constant time.

The two versions presented by OP rely on *addition* only.

For multiplication, the situation would be less trivial. Suffice it to say it's in a worse complexity class than addition is.

A trivial upper bound for the addition of two binary numbers is the number of bits in them, so O(log m), m being the larger of whatever two numbers you're adding.

For fixed-width integers, this is usually just simplified to O(1). Here we don't have that. Here the numbers actually grow severely and a single addition isn't that simple.

---

**Both** versions you present use memoization. That means storing intermediate results so they can be reused with O(1) effort once they're calculated.

If those results are stored in a "hashmap" (second version), that might not be in O(1) exactly but close enough ("amortized").

---

The "first version" of your code has two deficiencies:

- it doesn't keep the memoization cache across calls
- it lugs along all intermediate results, when it only *needs* the preceding three

It has one advantage: it's using a loop, not language recursion, so there's no finite stack depth to exhaust

---

The "second version" also **does not** keep its memoization cache across calls and it keeps all intermediate results.

It has another deficiency: it uses the language stack, which is finite, so it will stop working near arguments of size 1000.

---

Both versions strictly calculate every result once from component results of (n-1, n-2, n-3).

*If* addition is in O(1), then they're both in O(n).

---

If your teacher needs you to incorporate the cost of addition, then you would need to think about how fast this "tribonacci" sequence grows.

Assuming it grows exponentially, i.e. `trib(k) ~ exp(k)`, then each operation `trib(k)`, being addition, costs about `log(exp(k))` which is just `k`. The sum of the costs of all calculations from the start to `n` is the sum over those `k`, which is `n^2` (omitting the factor).

So... strictly speaking... both versions would be in O(n^2).

---

Kelly Bundy already offers an improvement on your first version that reduces the space complexity.

---

You might be tickled to learn that [*fib*onacci can be calculated in log(n) operations by using matrix exponentiation](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Fibonacci_matrix-exponentiation).

That's not just addition though, but multiplication, so each operation costs more, is no longer in O(n) per operation.

The same idea can be applied to this tribonacci. The matrix simply expresses a single step:

```
import numpy as np

T = np.array([
    [1, 1, 1], # c' = c+b+a
    [1, 0, 0], # b' = c
    [0, 1, 0]  # a' =   b
], dtype=object) # so we can keep using python integers

def tribonacci_matrix(n):
    return np.linalg.matrix_power(T, n)[2, 0]
```

I'm using numpy here only for the simple way to express matrix multiplication and exponentiation. It's just a container for *Python* integers.

This `T^n` can be calculated from (matrix) squaring and (matrix) multiplication, depending on whether n is even or odd. It takes O(log(n)) such operations, in contrast to the two versions you presented, which take O(n) operations.

This too will eventually crawl to a halt. I am not inclined to work out the *exact* time complexity of this. This is just an upper bound. Taking O(n^1.58) for efficient multiplication (Karatsuba), the time complexity should be at most O(log(n) * n^1.58). That's already below O(n^2).

Of course, reality adds cost in all kinds of places. I can't predict what an actual implementation might do or how timings behave. I'm content with OP not wasting memory or calculating the same thing twice.

Comment: *"A trivial upper bound for the addition of two binary numbers is the number of bits of them, so O(log n)"* - I think you mean O(number of bits). The name n is already taken here, and the numbers we're dealing with take O(n) to add, not O(log n).

Comment: The complexity of the matrix solution is implementation-dependent. Assuming the usual exponentiation by squaring, if multiplication of an M-bit number and an N-bit number takes &Theta;(MN) time, then I think the matrix solution is no better than O(n^2). But at least CPython (I don't know about other implementations) uses Karatsuba for large numbers, making multiplication and the whole matrix solution indeed better than O(n^2) in CPython.

Comment: the number of bits of a number is roughly log(that number). addition is linear in the number of bits in the worst case. that is what I mean. -- the point of the matrix exponentiation is that it takes `log(n)` (somewhat complex) steps rather than `n` simple steps. yes, multiplication is involved, not just addition. that would be a factor in the cost. I wasn't going to spend the time to work through all *that* too. I'm content to have presented the reasoning to arrive at the O(n^2) in your answer.

Comment: Well, "somewhat complex" is a bit of an understatement :-). It uses much slower operations *and* its numbers grow much faster. Those two things make it not that much faster. I was disappointed when I realized that some years ago, in a context where I think exponentiation by squaring was really *no* better than the naive alternative. It really shines when you do something like calculating tribonacci numbers modulo a small constant like 1000000007, since then the overall runtime is O(log n).

Comment: (continuing...)  I btw timed your matrix solution now with large numbers, looks like doubling n makes it take 3 times longer (7 seconds for n=2000000, and 21 seconds for n=4000000), exactly what you'd expect from Karatsuba's complexity. So with CPython, I think the complexity of that matrix solution is O(n^1.585).

Comment: I think you can drop the log(n) from the complexity. The matrix elements grow exponentially, making the last of the log(n) steps dominate all previous steps. If the elements in each step become twice as long (as "squaring" does), then with Karatsuba each step takes 3 times as long as the previous. So it's like the steps take 1, 3, 9, 27, 81, etc time. The 81 is more than the sum of all previous steps combined. Nitpick: strictly speaking, Karatsuba isn't O(n^1.58), because the exponent is slightly larger than 1.58. That's why I said O(n^1.585) (which is correct, just not as tight as possible).

Answer (score 0):

There are already good answers here so I am hesitant to post new answers, but so far none of the answers mentioned more efficient ways to compute the tribonacci numbers.

Using recursion is generally a bad idea, as a rule of thumb, recursion is generally slower than iteration, and in Python this is very true.

First of all the textbook recursion algorithm is quite dumb and others have explained why it is inefficient and I won't repeat it here.

A smarter approach would be to use the recursive relation iteratively, like so:

```
def trib(n: int) -> int:
    a, b, c = 0, 0, 1
    for _ in range(n):
        a, b, c = b, c, a + b + c
    return a
```

This is already much faster than the recursive approach but this is still inefficient, being linear time.

A smarter approach would be using matrix multiplication, Trib[0] = Trib[1] = 0, Trib[2] = 1, and Trib[n] = [[1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]] ^ (n - 3).

More information can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41667/fibonacci-tribonacci-and-other-similar-sequences), my mathematics isn't very good so I won't explain it in more detail.

Now because there is exponentiation involved it can be done in logarithmic time, because n^2 = n * n, n ^ 4 = n * n * n * n, a naive approach to compute n^4 would be to do 3 multiplications, this is inefficient, because we can first compute the square and multiply the square by the square, this is done in two multiplications. This isn't impressive here, but with three multiplications we can raise to 8th power, because the exponents add up when you multiply them.

This is called exponentiation by squaring. Google for the Wikipedia article for more information.

Now, the code:

```
import numba as nb
import numpy as np

ONE = np.array([[1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]], dtype=np.uint64)


def tribonacci(n: int) -> int:
    if n < 2:
        return 0

    if n == 2:
        return 1

    p = ONE.copy()
    base = ONE.copy()
    n -= 3
    while n:
        if n & 1:
            p = base @ p

        base = base @ base
        n >>= 1

    return p[0][0]
```

This is much more efficient algorithmically, but unfortunately each iteration is much more complex and thus slower, and Python is slow in general, so the code is slower than the naive approach:

```
In [167]: [trib(i) for i in range(16)]
Out[167]: [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 4, 7, 13, 24, 44, 81, 149, 274, 504, 927, 1705]

In [168]: [tribonacci(i) for i in range(16)]
Out[168]: [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 4, 7, 13, 24, 44, 81, 149, 274, 504, 927, 1705]

In [169]: %timeit tribonacci(75)
15.3 µs ± 86.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)

In [170]: %timeit trib(75)
7.27 µs ± 124 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
```

75 is the biggest place in the tribonacci series that doesn't exceed 2^64 - 1, the range of `np.uint64`.

I tried to speed it up with `numba`, and the result is much faster:

```
@nb.njit(cache=True, fastmath=True)
def matmul_3x3(a: np.ndarray, b: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    out = np.zeros(shape=(3, 3), dtype=np.uint64)
    for y in (0, 1, 2):
        for x in (0, 1, 2):
            s = 0
            for z in (0, 1, 2):
                s += a[y, z] * b[z, x]
            
            out[y, x] = s

    return out


@nb.njit(cache=True)
def tribonacci_nb(n: int) -> int:
    if n < 2:
        return 0

    if n == 2:
        return 1

    p = ONE.copy()
    base = ONE.copy()
    n -= 3
    while n:
        if n & 1:
            p = matmul_3x3(base, p)

        base = matmul_3x3(base, base)
        n >>= 1

    return p[0][0]
```

```
In [171]: %timeit tribonacci_nb(75)
1.67 µs ± 37.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)
```

I have no idea why it gives a `float` though, the other smart function gives an `int`.

```
In [172]: tribonacci_nb(75)
Out[172]: 1.2903063846126135e+19

In [173]: tribonacci(75)
Out[173]: 12903063846126135669
```

---

Performance benchmark of the answers so far, I have fixed the `tribonacci_matrix` function from the currently only upvoted answer.

```
import numba as nb
import numpy as np

ONE = np.array([[1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]], dtype=np.uint64)


def trib(n: int) -> int:
    a, b, c = 0, 0, 1
    for _ in range(n):
        a, b, c = b, c, a + b + c
    return a


def tribonacci(n: int) -> int:
    if n < 2:
        return 0

    if n == 2:
        return 1

    p = ONE.copy()
    base = ONE.copy()
    n -= 3
    while n:
        if n & 1:
            p = base @ p

        base = base @ base
        n >>= 1

    return p[0][0]


@nb.njit(cache=True, fastmath=True)
def matmul_3x3(a: np.ndarray, b: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    out = np.zeros(shape=(3, 3), dtype=np.uint64)
    for y in (0, 1, 2):
        for x in (0, 1, 2):
            s = 0
            for z in (0, 1, 2):
                s += a[y, z] * b[z, x]
            
            out[y, x] = s

    return out


@nb.njit(cache=True)
def tribonacci_nb(n: int) -> int:
    if n < 2:
        return 0

    if n == 2:
        return 1

    p = ONE.copy()
    base = ONE.copy()
    n -= 3
    while n:
        if n & 1:
            p = matmul_3x3(base, p)

        base = matmul_3x3(base, base)
        n >>= 1

    return p[0][0]


def tribonacci_matrix(n):
    return np.linalg.matrix_power(ONE, n)[2, 0]
```

```
In [186]: [tribonacci_matrix(i) for i in range(16)]
Out[186]: [0, 1, 1, 2, 4, 7, 13, 24, 44, 81, 149, 274, 504, 927, 1705, 3136]

In [187]: [tribonacci(i) for i in range(16)]
Out[187]: [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 4, 7, 13, 24, 44, 81, 149, 274, 504, 927, 1705]

In [188]: [tribonacci_nb(i) for i in range(16)]
Out[188]:
[0.0,
 0.0,
 1.0,
 1.0,
 2.0,
 4.0,
 7.0,
 13.0,
 24.0,
 44.0,
 81.0,
 149.0,
 274.0,
 504.0,
 927.0,
 1705.0]

In [189]: [trib(i) for i in range(16)]
Out[189]: [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 4, 7, 13, 24, 44, 81, 149, 274, 504, 927, 1705]

In [190]: %timeit trib(75)
7.48 µs ± 62 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)

In [191]: %timeit tribonacci(75)
15.4 µs ± 56.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)

In [192]: %timeit tribonacci_matrix(75)
25.2 µs ± 562 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)

In [193]: %timeit tribonacci_nb(75)
1.65 µs ± 13.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)
```

`tribonacci_nb` is by far the fastest, `np.linalg.matrix_power` is surprisingly the slowest, I have beaten it even without using `numba`. Also, according to Wikipedia the second term of tribonacci sequence is 0, not 1.