# ways to reach the n’th stair but with given conition

Tags: java, algorithm

There are `n` stairs, a person standing at the bottom wants to reach the top. The person can climb either 1 stair or 2 stairs at a time.

Now I want to find the **minimum number of steps needed that are divisible by given number m**.

Here is the java program which I created using [this as a reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32818911/print-ways-to-reach-the-n-th-stair), which is used to print the possible steps:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        int n = 10, m = 2;
        List<Integer> vals = new ArrayList<>();
        Set<String> set = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.reverseOrder());
        ClimbWays(n, 0, new int[n], vals, set);

        set.forEach(a -> {
            System.out.println(a + " : " + a.length());
        });
    }

    public static void ClimbWays(int n, int currentIndex, int[] currectClimb, List<Integer> vals, Set<String> set) {
        if (n < 0)
            return;

        if (n == 0) {
            vals.add(currentIndex);
            int last = 0;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = currentIndex - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                int current = currectClimb[i];
                int res = current - last;
                last = current;
                sb.append(res);
            }
            String s = sb.toString();
            char[] c = s.toCharArray();
            Arrays.sort(c);
            s = new String(c);
            set.add(s);
            return;
        }

        currectClimb[currentIndex] = n;
        ClimbWays(n - 1, currentIndex + 1, currectClimb, vals, set);
        ClimbWays(n - 2, currentIndex + 1, currectClimb, vals, set);
    }
```

Output of the program is :

```
22222 : 5
112222 : 6
1111222 : 7
11111122 : 8
111111112 : 9
1111111111 : 10
```

Now for steps 10 if I want to get minimum steps divisible by m = 2, then the solution is `112222` which has 6 as the number of steps needed.

This program basically finds all possible pairs then add them to tree set. Next, I can loop through this set and get the minimum element divisible by given input `m`.

Is there a better approach to do this?

Comment: I did not understand your question. Could you please explain it in more detail?

Comment: @Bugman, I updated the question to clarify, you can also refer to the link which I added in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the person can climb a maximum of 2 steps at a time, the minimum number of steps to climb n stairs is

```
x = n/2 if n is even
x = n/2 + 1 if n is odd
```

Now you need to find the minimum number of steps to climb n stairs which is divisible by m. Meaning you need to find a number immediate next to x which is divisible by m.

```
if x%m == 0 then x is your answer
if x%m != 0 then ((x/m) + 1) * m is your answer.
```

Now speaking of your example

```
For n = 10, 
x = n/2 = 5,
x%m = 5 % 2 = 1 != 0
Thus ans = ((5/2) + 1) * 2 = 6
```